# Retrieve data between dates in laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, query-builder

I am using an eloquent query to retrieve data from a table. The table columns look like this:

`id   started_at   finished_at`
`1    06/02/2019   06/15/2019`
`2    06/05/2019   06/11/2019`

What I want to do is, given a `$date` (ex: 06/08/2019 ) and get the data of the row, that the $date between started at and finished_at columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 DB::table('table_name')->whereBetween('started_at', [$date1, $date2])
  ->orWhereBetween('finished_at', [$date1, $date2])->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$data = Model::where('started_at', '<', $date)->where('finished_at', '>', $date)->first();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$date = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($started_at));


$data = Model::where('started_at', '>', $date)->where('finished_at', '<', $date)->first();
```